# Resource database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to know what the Resource Database in SQL Server is, and why can't we see this physical file in the SQL Server installed directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Resource database is a read-only database that contains all the system objects that are included with SQL Server.
>
> The physical file names of the Resource database are mssqlsystemresource.mdf and mssqlsystemresource.ldf. These files are located in :\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.\MSSQL\Binn.

http://www.google.lv/#hl=ru&source=hp&q=SQL+Server+Resource+Database&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=9fb3269afe873631
FIRST(!!) link

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at [MSDN?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190940%28SQL.90%29.aspx) It has information on paths etc

If you still can't see it then it's flagged as "hidden" and/or "system" in NTFS